# Unable to hit a URL even after encoding

Tags: java, json, encoding, special-characters

I've got a JSON string which I encode and then append to a REST URL. But the problem is due to certain special characters the request is not going through.
My JSON String is as follows

```
{"empName":"Jammy","fromDateRaw":"06-11-2014 ","fromDate":"Fri May 06 00:00:00 IST 12","travelRequestNumber":"2000070293","toDate":"Sun May 06 00:00:00 IST 36","mobileNumber":"","requestedOn":"Thu Oct 16 00:52:17 IST 2014","comments":"Employee prefer the following hotel and room type:Residence Inn Dallas Addison/Quorum Drive 14975 Quorum Drive?Dallas, Texas 75254 USA"}
```

Even though I'm encoding the URL it's not going through because the last one "Comments" has 3 special characters in it which are ":/?". If I remove the three characters and encode this URL and append this to the REST API it goes through. But I need these characters in place, any ideas how I can escape these characters?

Comment: Show us how you encode it.

Comment: "append to a REST URL" -- which part of the URL? Path? Query string? Fragment?

Comment: Which means I have like http://9.21.1.12:9091/RestManager/rest/APIMapper/ and the encoded URL follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class to encode text which you plan to append to urls, like this:

```
String text = ""; // Insert your text here
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
```

`URLEncoder` properly escapes all special characters, you can safely append `encoded` to URL strings.

**Applying to your string:**

Note that if the input is specified in Java source you have to escape the quotes (with `\"`).

```
    String text = "{\"empName\":\"Jammy\",\"fromDateRaw\":\"06-11-2014 \",\"fromDate\":\"Fri May 06 00:00:00 IST 12\",\"travelRequestNumber\":\"2000070293\",\"toDate\":\"Sun May 06 00:00:00 IST 36\",\"mobileNumber\":\"\",\"requestedOn\":\"Thu Oct 16 00:52:17 IST 2014\",\"comments\":\"Employee prefer the following hotel and room type:Residence Inn Dallas Addison/Quorum Drive 14975 Quorum Drive?Dallas, Texas 75254 USA\"}";
    String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(encoded);
```

Output:

```
%7B%22empName%22%3A%22Jammy%22%2C%22fromDateRaw%22%3A%2206-11-2014+%22%2C%22fromDate%22%3A%22Fri+May+06+00%3A00%3A00+IST+12%22%2C%22travelRequestNumber%22%3A%222000070293%22%2C%22toDate%22%3A%22Sun+May+06+00%3A00%3A00+IST+36%22%2C%22mobileNumber%22%3A%22%22%2C%22requestedOn%22%3A%22Thu+Oct+16+00%3A52%3A17+IST+2014%22%2C%22comments%22%3A%22Employee+prefer+the+following+hotel+and+room+type%3AResidence+Inn+Dallas+Addison%2FQuorum+Drive+14975+Quorum+Drive%3FDallas%2C+Texas+75254+USA%22%7D
```

You can append it to a URL like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://somehost.com/something?data=" + encoded);
```

Comment: Nope, I did almost the same thing... It's not working.

Comment: Edited the anser. See the output, it has no special characters. Also added example howto append it to a URL text, it produces no errors.

Comment: I get the encoded URL, but the problem is the encoded URL is not giving me any result, I only get the result from Tomcat when I remove these 3 special characters.

Comment: `URLEncoder` is almost never the good answer; it does the job correctly 90+% of the time but fails miserably otherwise. The only broadly available library right now which can encode correctly is Guava, or a dedicated URI template library.

Comment: @Vineeth You are clearly not showing us something. If you use the URL created at the end of my answer, at the server side (e.g. Tomcat servlet) the `request.getParameter("data")` will give you back exactly the input JSON string. Note that if the input is specified in Java source you have to escape the quotes (with `\"`).

Comment: @icza I'm using the same code that you've given me. But I'm not getting any response from Tomcat. Before encoding if I remove the "/" and "?" and then encode it works... Even I'm confused...

Comment: Simple: any query string parameter where you have a space in it. This class will turn spaces into `+` whereas the URI encoding scheme expects `%20`. That is but one pitfall.

Comment: And anyway, the class description mentions it: it is meant to encode data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding; which is _very_ different from URI encoding. For instance, a `+` character is left intact in a URI fragment part -- which this class doesn't. (but in a _path_ component, `+` is turned into the matching percent escape). Again, your best bet is to use a dedicated URI template library. It will work each and every time.

Comment: @fge Thanks for the info. Then in this case the `URI` class itself is capable to properly encode. Example: `String query="data=Something wierd+"`, using `URI`: `new URI("http", null, "somehost.com", 80, "/something", query, null)` results in `"http://somehost.com:80/something?data=Something%20wierd+"`. Here space is converted to `%20` and the plus sign is left intact. Can you confirm this is correct?

Comment: Yep, the URI class works fine in this case and in fact, for 80+% of use cases; URI templates allow for more fine grained expansion however. For instance, `http://foo.bar/?param={value}` where `value` is a variable